# Rails 3.1: howto include oocss CSS framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oocss

I am trying to load the [OOCSS](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss) framework into my new Rails 3.1 application. So far I have clone the project into /vendor/assists/stysheets/oocss, and tried to pull in the project from /app/assists/stylesheets/application.css

```
/*
 * FIXME: Introduce SCSS & Sprockets
 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/all
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

However this does not work properbly, as the compiled css file just contains the two lines that should load the other files.

```
@import url("core/core.css");
@import url("plugins/plugins.css");
/*
 * FIXME: Introduce SCSS & Sprockets
*/
/* 
  Place all the styles related to the matching controller here.
  They will automatically be included in application.css.
  You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
*/
/* 
  Place all the styles related to the matching controller here.
  They will automatically be included in application.css.
  You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
*/
/* 
  Place all the styles related to the matching controller here.
  They will automatically be included in application.css.
  You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
*/
```

Any ideas on how to pull this off?

**UPDATE:**
I did a dirty workaround by manually loading the CSS files in the correct order.

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
/*
 * FIXME: Introduce SCSS & Sprockets
 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss.css.scss

```
/*
 * Core 
 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/libraries.css
 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/template/template.css
 * require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/template/template_debug.css

 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/grid/grids.css
 * require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/grid/grids_debug.css

 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/module/mod.css
 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/module/mod_skins.css
 * require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/module/mod_debug.css

 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/media/media.css
 * require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/media/media_debug.css

 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/content.css
 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/heading/heading.css
 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/spacing/space.css

 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/table/table.css
 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/table/table_skins.css
 * require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/core/table/table_debug.css

 * Plugins
 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/plugins/breadcrumb/breadcrumb.css
 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/plugins/tabs/tabs.css
 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/plugins/talk/talk.css
 *= require ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/oocss/plugins/talk/talk_skins.css
*/
```

Best regards.
Asbjørn Morell